# importxml problem with a table with merged cells

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I'm trying to import a table but it seems the contents have some problems with merged cells. Check this [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13I7AW8631AF81lci35j79YSyazp99M4Pl-0RkVrCJkA/edit#gid=0) for example (original wiki article and table is [this](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/KTX-I#%EC%98%81%EC%97%85_%EA%B5%AC%EA%B0%84)). importxml just pushed the contents from the second column onward to where the vertically merged cells are in the first column. How can I import a table intact just like importhtml?

Comment: Why do you not just use importhtml instead?

Comment: I was trying to apply the same function for several different pages but I guess I'll have to use importhtml